# RSelenium couldn't connect to host

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

I wrote a web-scraping program using RSelenium.  It works perfectly on my computer.  When I try to send it to my co-workers, it gives me a "couldn't connect to host" error message. Here is the code I have them run, prior to navigating to the url.

The error occurs after executing the remDr$open() command, but I'm sure the error is rooted in a earlier line.  When executing this code on my computer, the Java command console pops up after executing the RSelenium::startServer() command.

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("stringr")
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("RSelenium")

require(devtools)
require(stringr)
require(RSelenium) 
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

RSelenium::checkForServer(update=TRUE)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr=remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
```

Here is the R sessionInfo on the computer that is having trouble running it:

> R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           [5]
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] RSelenium_1.3.1 XML_3.98-1.1
>   caTools_1.17    RJSONIO_1.3-0   RCurl_1.95-4.3  [6] bitops_1.0-6
>   stringr_0.6.2   devtools_1.5
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] digest_0.6.4
>   evaluate_0.5.5 httr_0.4       memoise_0.2.1  parallel_3.0.3 [6]
>   tools_3.0.3    whisker_0.3-2

Comment: the Selenium server constantly is a few versions behind the latest browser. Can you make sure the browser is compatible with the Selenium version?

Comment: Your friend will need java installed on their machine if windows

Comment: It is hard to say without more detail. Please file an issue on https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium

Comment: @jdharrison - thank you.  I realized I muffed the Java installation on their machine earlier.  I just fixed this.  However, even though Java pops up and no error message is given, the browser fails to open. I get the following message: 

"GET /session/\nBuild info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:14'\nSystem info: host: 'MR3334', ip: '10.5.0.80', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown"